# Adding Acces-Control-Allow-Origin to app.yml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cors

I'm following these instructions from Google App Engine docs :

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref

If you search for CORS, you'll see the example I am trying to copy.

My app.yaml file looks like:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  http_headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

However when I go to update it I get this error:

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing ./app.yaml: Unable to assign value 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to attribute 'http_headers':
Value 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for http_headers is not of the expected type HttpHeadersDict
```

Why am I getting this error? What am I doing differently than the docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not valid [yaml](http://yaml.org/).

You have an indentation problem. Also you have to quote the `*`. Should be:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  http_headers: 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```